# Как отключить анимацию при обновление страницы transform и transfition

Tags: html, css

Мне нужно, чтобы при обновление страницы не было начальной анимации, а сразу кнопка была такой, какая она на втором фото

[image: Начало]
Это самое начало при обновление страницы (не обращайте внимание на остальное, кроме кнопки, которая меняется)

[image: После]
Это после анимации и обновления страницы

"Если навести мышкой на эту кнопку, то она плавно уменьшится. Только так и должно работать. А начальная анимация не нужна"

```css
#suda{
    text-align: center;
    color: purple;
    font-size: 40px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    background-color: pink;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-right: 200px;
    margin-left: 200px;
    border-radius: 200px;
    opacity: 0.7;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px grey;
    transform: scale(0.8);
    transition: 1s all;

}

#suda:hover{
    opacity: 1;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px grey;
    transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.7);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Тест</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="suda"><a id="none" href="ссылка">Если хочешь послушать музыку, тогда тебе сюда)</a></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Сейчас никаких анимаций не происходит при загрузке при таком коде

Comment: ? У меня есть анимация, просто мне не нужна начальная при обновлении страницы

Comment: Значит это не весь css и js который есть на сайте. Сейчас описанная проблема не воспроизводится

Comment: У вас нет такой проблемы?

Comment: Нет такой проблемы. Смотрю правда в сниппете на этом сайте

Comment: s jsfiffle тоже всё норм

Comment: Ну у меня она всё ещё есть. Если убрать из #suda строчку transition: 1s; то этой проблемы не будет, но плавная анимация пропадёт

Comment: Её можно добавить в #suda:hover и она появится, но убрав мышку кнопка резко вернётся обратно. А мне нужна обратная анимация, чтобы убрав мышку, кнопка так же плавно возвращалась обратно

Comment: Отредактировал ваш код, в приведенном вами примере - нет проблемы, которую вы описываете.