# Как применить keyframes для css, чтобы убрать ошибку с анимациями?

Tags: html, css

Всем ку, уже задаю третий раз по данной теме вопрос. Как мне можно исправить ошибку. Я обновляю страницу и срабатывает анимация, которая не должна быть, ведь анимация должна срабатывать лишь тогда, когда я навожу мышкой на кнопку. Я понял, что проблема в одно строчке кода, но убрав её не срабатывает анимация в обратную сторону. Все пишут про keyframe, но прочитав статью, я до сих пор не понимаю, как применить это для решения моей проблемы

Comment: без вашего кода невозможно дать ответ на ваш вопрос, ибо у нас таких проблем как у вас - НЕТ!

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как отключить анимацию при обновление страницы transform и transfition](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1303895/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b-transform-%d0%b8-transfition)

Comment: Это уже **третья** копия одного и того же вопроса: первый вопрос указан связанным (с этим очередным дубликатом), а [вот второй (предыдущий)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1303913/288409). Вместо многократных повторений вопроса, надо исправить тот который был задан первым.

Answer (score 0):

Без кода трудно понять в чем ошибка.
Но вот база с помощью которой будет работать анимация:

```
.element:hover{       
   animation: myAnimation 1s linear 0s forwards;
   // (animation: <название> <длительность> <скорость> (<задержка>, можно не указывать) forwards)
   // forwards в конце чтобы конечный результат анимации сохранился
}
@keyframes myAnimation{
   from{
        Начальное состояние
   }
   to{
        Конечное состояние
   }
}
```